# Migration of schema PUBLIC to version 1.2 failed

Tags: java, swing, flyway

Am writing **swing database application** in **springToolset**-eclipse based IDE and **maven**. so here is my simple db connection code and migrate it with flyway.

**Main class**

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws SQLException {
        final BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:target/db");
        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("");

        try {
          final Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
          flyway.setDataSource(ds);
          flyway.migrate(); // line no :12
    }}
```

**Schema_name** as per flyway(2.2.1) standard is :

> V1__init_db.sql

And when i run this code i got this error :

```
  Exception in thread "main" com.googlecode.flyway.core.api.FlywayException: 
Migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version 1.2 failed! Please restore backups and roll back database and code!
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:199)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:872)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:819)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1200)
        at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:819)
        at com.swdb.exApp.Main.main(12)
```

any one knows what is the error.please help.
and also this is a tutoiral from **Alber Attard** [here](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-java-database-swing-application/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your database. Flyway has previously run against the configured schema and a migration failed. If you can discard the schema, simply issue `flyway.clean()` and you should be able to start fresh. IF not, you must perform the cleanup manually before proceeding.

Comment: i deleted the previously generated database in the **target/db**, and it solved the problem for me, thank u for the replay...

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by the developer of Flyway, there was an issue when running the migration.

Ideally we start from scratch.  The database is created in a folder called `db` within the `target` directory (`ds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:target/db");`).  Delete the `db` directory.  This will delete the database all things in it.  This will cause the Flyway to start again and execute the migration scripts.

Please make sure that you are using the correct versions.  This tutorial makes us of the following versions (which dependencies are managed through Maven):

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.173</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I believe some newer versions of H2 are not compatible with these examples and my cause problems.

Can you please try this out?

Regards,
Albert Attard

Answer (score 0):

The 'Migration of schema "PUBLIC" to version X.X failed!' can often appear on the console or in report files, but may be masking a more serious error with the SQL. When I got this issue, I later noticed that the target/db folder had a file called .trace.db. When I looked in this trace file in text editor, it showed me the exact SQL error I was getting, in my case I was trying to insert with an invalid column name.